# In MySQL Workbench, same output shown multiple times and by executing query, output rows increases by one

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables:

`Citizen_Location` where it has Name and Location:

[image: Citizen_Location]

`Citizens` where it contains Name, Age & Exp:

[image: Citizen]

So, I've performed `join` operation in it:

```
select c.name,cl.location 
from citizens as c 
    join citizen_location as cl;
```

Output:

```
***564 row(s)*** returned   0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Whenever I hit the execute button, that rows gets increased by 1 by default. Also, even executing normal query, output always shown twice and as your keep hitting execute button, it keeps increasing!

I tried to open new query tab and reinstalled the program but the problem remains the same. Everytime same output shown twice and thrice and so on.

I am getting output like this [image: Output looks like]

Comment: No JOIN condition?!?

Comment: `join citizen_location as cl ON c.name = cl.name`

Comment: JOIN condition might not be necessary if it is about **natural join**, @jarlh, as database then "knows" it should join foreign key column in one table with primary key column in another.

Comment: @jarlh the thing is im getting same rows multiple times. it doesn't matter if im performing joins or something else

Comment: OK, so you are going to have to show us your schema, and provide some test data. If you do that as a dbfiddle we can all see it and check an answer before making one. [See dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) OR [Other Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Since you have no `ON` condition, you're getting a complete cartesian product of the two tabls.

Comment: @Littlefoot, do you mean MySQL's `JOIN` without `ON`/`USING` means `NATURAL JOIN`? I thought it meant `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @Littlefoot MySQL doesn't do natural join automatically. You have to use the `NATURAL JOIN` keyword, then it joins by all the columns with the same name (not specifically foreign keys).

Comment: Sorry, guys - I was fooled by Oracle SQL Developer tag and didn't pay attention to database the OP uses. In Oracle, `join` is *inner join*. It also requires explicitly named `natural join`, just as Barmar said. My bad, I apologize.

Comment: I've added output screen as well. So, you can get idea that how am i getting the output

Comment: **TL/DR** So i built the basic fiddle for you. If the schema is wrong in any way correct it and post the updated fiddle address here [Start fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LUZfGPXn) Includes a query with an ON CLAUSE

Comment: @Palkit Rathod: The explanation and solution (missing join condition) have been given to you right away. If you still haven't understood the issue by now: you are showing subhash with rahul's california and with george's california and with steve's california, etc., because you tell the DBMS to combine all rows (every person with every address combination), instead of telling the DBMS to give you the address belonging to the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN` in SQL. It must be followed by a join condition which is either an `ON` clause or a `USING` clause. You have neither, so MySQL should raise a syntax error here. It can be considered a flaw in the DBMS that it doesn't.

Obviously, MySQL turns your `JOIN` into a `CROSS JOIN` instead, i.e. an inconditional join. Thus you join every row of the left table with every row of the right table.

The solution to your problem is simple: Just add a condition.

```
select c.name, cl.location 
from citizens as c 
join citizen_location as cl on cl.name = c.name;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/dVYYtUGB

Comment: May i know the reason of "on cl.name = c.name;" this part

Comment: A join combines rows from two tables. In this join you have a citizens row. Now you are looking for a matching citizen_location row. For this to happen, you must tell the DBMS how to determine which citizen_location row matches the citizens row. The condition for this is that the citizen_location row's name must equal the citizens row's name.